# SQLALCHEMY: filter result if a value is in a list

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi

I have a list of values and I want to filter this sqlalchemy query based on if a value is in that list. Something like this:

```
def get_values(db: Session= 
l = [23, 34, 54]
qr = db.query(table).filter(table.column in l).all()
return qr
```

Thanks

Comment: `.filter(Model.column_id.in_(l))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `in_` method on columns:

```
qr = db.query(table).filter(Model.column_id.in_(l)).all()
```

(Make sure you keep the underscore (`_`) at the end of `in`)